# Where does wget save to?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2, wget

I installed Ubuntu on my server and then I ran this

```
wget -O- 'http://ktd.joodle.nl/KS2008R2.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda
```

and then the tutorial says "**Once fully downloaded and unzipped to the disk** go back to the Kimsufi control panel and change Netboot to Hard Disk. Once done, reboot the server and **wait till it responds to ping. After that you can login using RDP** (Remote Desktop Control)".

Now, I don't think I unzipped it, then I changed to Hard Disk, waited about 10 min but RDC didn't work. 
I went back to Netboot rescue mode but I don't know the location of the file. Can someone help me??

This is the site I followed the tutorial from:
https://joodle.nl/install-windows-on-a-kimsufi-server/

Thanks.

Comment: You ran a command, which you don't fully understand, that `dd`s your `/dev/sda`? Color me impressed. As it says on the page "Need help? Send me an email at joodle@joodle.nl !!"

Comment: From a completely random website, too. That's just asking for trouble. There could be _anything_ in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran the command as is, `wget` didn't save anything anywhere. The option `-O-` writes to standard output, in this case to the pipe connecting to `gunzip`. Any data downloaded is fed to `gunzip`. `gnuzip` extracts whatever it gets from standard input, and writes the extracted content to standard output, this time to the pipe connecting to `dd`. `dd` writes to `/dev/sda`.

In short: There's no *file* that you can look for. The full command takes care of downloading and unzipping to disk.

And since it is a 4.6GB file, it should be pretty clear from the progress output of `wget` whether the command was successful.

Answer (score -2):

Normally, wget would save to whatever directory you are currently working in so run `ls` to see the contents, or `pwd` to see what directory (or just look at the beginning of the line`.

**EDIT:**
If you know the name of the file, or part of the name, you can run `sudo find / -name 'filename'*` to find it, replacing what's inside the quotes with what you know of the filename (get rid of the quotes unless your filename has spaces). Also, these commands will **run on Linux, not Windows**.

Comment: In theory, the filename would be `KS2008R2.gz`, but it might have been changed during the time your command was run.

Comment: what's up with the downvotes? what he says is correct.

Comment: @EdH he's missing the `-O-` - `wget` is writing out to stdout and not saving to a file. `gunzip` is then reading in from stdin and extracting. In all this, the only indication on disk (except for the effect of `dd`) that something's being downloaded would be the pipes that the shell setup.

Comment: Well, I do think the file name has been changed too; I am using Bitvise and was on / when I ran the command on the console. ls says it can't find it, pwd only shows /root for any file I type in and sudo find / -name 'KS2008R2'* returns me nothing.

Comment: @muru That makes sense. So the OP should just not do stdin, and just save the file, then run gunzip.

Comment: @HSoares The file isn't being saved anywhere **technically**, it's just in a buffer, so the filename doesn't matter. I had missed that in the question.

Comment: @HSoares Just get rid of the stdin parts, and then run gunzip on the downloaded file from wget

Comment: @techgod52 Okay, sorry for the noobish question, how do I get rid of the stdin parts? I do recall something saying stdout while it was downloading.

Comment: @HSoares np, just remove the `-O-` part of the command and get rid of everything after the `|`. It will save the file to the current directory you are in, and then you can run gunzip on it.

Comment: @techgod52 Oh, seems easy then :) I'll do that in the morning and then I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks for your help! ^_^

Comment: @HSoares Ok, good luck!